# Trying to solve conic for ellipse equation

Tags: conic-sections

I'm trying to find out what conic the following equation represents.

$9x^2+4y^2+18x-16y+24 = 0$

I know that the general ellipse equation is $(x^2)/a + (y^2)/b = 1.$

I got $9(x+1)^2 + 4(y-2)^2 = 1$, but I am not sure what to do next.

For example if I had some number instead of $1$, I could easily divide everything and get the "correct" equation pattern, but since I already have a $1$ on the right, I am not sure what to do.

Regards,
L.K.

Comment: Your very first expression is missing an " = " somewhere and another number/expression in the other side of this symbol

Comment: Most probably you can't comment as you're still lacking reputation points, but you can edit your question and add the missing info.

Comment: I approved nsanger edit, thank you for the corrections.

Comment: Now you have some rep. points...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, for some reason, what you say you get is correct then

$$9(x+1)^2+4(y-2)^2=1\iff \frac{(x+1)^2}{\frac19}+\frac{(y-2)^2}{\frac14}=1\implies a=\frac13\;,\;b=\frac12$$

Remember that for any non-zero number $\;a\;$ , we have

$$a=\frac1{\frac1a}$$

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but didn't you mean (y-2)^2 instead of (y-2)^4 ?

Comment: Yes, of course: typo. Thanks.